# Error on simple Select command?

Tags: syntax-error

I’m new to SQL, but can handle some very basic clauses. Can anyone tell me what’s wrong with the following statement?

```
SELECT top 10 * 
FROM inventory
WHERE UPC=‘104270’;
```

The error message is:

```
Incorrect syntax near ‘’’.
```

I’ve confirmed that all spelling is correct, including tablename  (inventory) and condition (UPC).

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `’` character instead of a single-quote `'`.
Replace your `’`s with `'`s and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions :**  `’` Replace with single-quote `'`

`SELECT top 10 * FROM inventory WHERE 'UPC'='104270';`

Helpful :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!